# NullPointerException TopLevelTransaction.markAsRollbackOnly Neo4J-Boot for findAll() method

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-boot

I am trying to follow Josh Long - Philip Sorst [example](https://github.com/joshlong/boot-examples/tree/master/x-auth-security) in order to perform Angular SPA-Rest Authentication and CRUD actions using Neo4J as db (excellent work. Thanks a lot guys). But I am stuck at a very early stage and I suspect it's not my fault. Please help Neo4J-Angular-Spring lovers. My code can be found [here](https://github.com/pvlastaridis/neo4jspringbootangular) and it is very easy to run just clone and give `mvn spring-boot:run`

Now the problem is that I get the following exception only for the findAll() method of the GraphRepository.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.markAsRollbackOnly(TopLevelTransaction.java:93)
    ... 88 common frames omitted
```

and I will replicate some of my code:

**Neo4JConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "demo.repository.neo4j")
public class Neo4JConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

  public Neo4JConfig() {
     setBasePackage("demo.model.neo4j");
  }

  @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
  public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {      
     return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("data/demo.db");             
  }

  @Bean
  public Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate() {
    return new Neo4jTemplate(graphDatabaseService());
  }
}
```

**NewsEntry.java**

```
@NodeEntity
public class NewsEntry {

  @GraphId
  private Long id;
  private String content;
  public NewsEntry() {}
    public NewsEntry(String b) {
     this.content = b;
    }

  public Long getId() {
      return this.id;
  }

  public String getContent() {
      return this.content;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
      this.id = id;
  }

  public void setContent(String content) {
      this.content = content;
  }
}
```

**NewsEntryRepository.java**

```
public interface NewsEntryRepository extends GraphRepository<NewsEntry> {   
}
```

**NewsEntryController.java**

```
@RestController
class NewsController {

 @Autowired
     private NewsEntryRepository newsEntryRepository;

 @RequestMapping("/news")
 List<NewsEntry> entries() {

 List<NewsEntry> list = new ArrayList<NewsEntry>();
 Iterable<NewsEntry> results = newsEntryRepository.findAll();
 for (NewsEntry r : results) {
   list.add(r);
 }
 return list;
  } 

  @RequestMapping(value = "/news/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
  void remove(@PathVariable Long id) {        
      this.newsEntryRepository.delete(id);
      return;
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/news/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  NewsEntry entry(@PathVariable Long id) {
      return this.newsEntryRepository.findOne(id);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/news/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  NewsEntry update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody NewsEntry news) {
      NewsEntry old  = this.newsEntryRepository.findOne(id);
      old = news;        
      return this.newsEntryRepository.save(old);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/news", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  NewsEntry add(@RequestBody NewsEntry news) {
      this.newsEntryRepository.save(new NewsEntry(news.getContent()));
      return news;
  }  
}
```

Comment: I had the problem initially too, but it went away after adding @EnableTransactionManagement, see my test-project: https://github.com/jexp/sdn-twitter-graph

Comment: Unfortunately I lost your webinar yesterday. Thanks for your code I will soon take a look. You have set up Neo4j in xml and I think the trick is preformed by line `<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"/>`. If this works next think I will try to get from cineasts `Userdetails` Implementation in order for Spring Security to work with nodes in the Graph. Have you seen a more modern implementation of Spring Security Userdetails and Neo4j?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK Solution inspired from here https://github.com/mstahv/bootiful-neo4j-with-vaadin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/neo4j/AppService.java. He is implementing a @Service annotated with @Transactional before using the repository in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to override:

```
  @Bean
  public Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate() {
    return new Neo4jTemplate(graphDatabaseService());
  }
```

And can you try to add the annotation:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
```

to your config?

Comment: Thank you for your immediate reply. This unfortunately does not help. The same exception is still thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Something is telling me that the solution is hiding somewhere [here](https://github.com/markjamesbutler/spring-boot-neo4j). I will give it a go and let you know.

OK This works only if you change the version of Spring-data-neo4j to 2.3.3.RELEASE. If you use the latest version you get the same problem as above. I think I should open an issue.

But that's not the solution as I would like to use Neo4J Server Community 2.0.3 to open the graph for visualization afterwards. Also I do not understand this solution beanfactories, injects instead of autowired???. However I will make another branch for this solution in my github repo.